# FLEX: if statement if constructor argument is not provided

Tags: actionscript-3

is good practice to use if(source==null) in my costructor, to run code only if the costructor argument is provided ?

```
package dataModels {

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import dataModels.*;


    [Bindable]
    public class TagsListModel extends ArrayCollection{

        public function TagsListModel( source:Array=null ) {

            if (source!=null) {
                super(source);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it's good practice or not, but if it works for you, it's good.